# Bulk Search Or Find a bunch of values at once

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, search, excel-online

I have a list of order numbers that I get from one sheet & cross check whether they are there in another sheet (they shouldn't be, they would be the orders that we don't need so we delete them from the main sheet).

What I do now, is get each number separately and CTRL+F to find whether they exist. Is there anyway that I can do this task in bulk.

Comment: While Excel and Google Sheets both are spreadsheet apps some features aren't available in one or the other and some might not behave the same way. What web application are you using?

Comment: @Ruben Google sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a fast, effienct way to find matches between two sets of order numbers.

Let's assume that one set of order numbers are in Sheet1 and this sheet is to be compared to those on Sheet2, and that row 1 in each sheet contains headers.

Enter this formula in Sheet1, Cell B2:

`=arrayformula(iferror(match(A2:A,Sheet2!$A$2:$A,0),""))`

This tests for a match for each order number in Column A of Sheet1 with an order number anywhere in Column A of Sheet2. If a match is found, then the Sheet2 row number is displayed; if there is no match, then nothing is displayed. You could use conditional formatting to highlight matches; you could also use control totals such as `COUNTIF` (to identify the number of matches).

---

Sheet1 |  Sheet 2

[image: Sheet1] | [image: sheet 2]

---